Determining serial dependence in irregularly spaced nominal observations in a categorical time series
I have data on fish movements up and down a river. Fish were tagged with ultrasonic pingers that allowed identification of individuals. Recording hydrophones were placed at various locations in the river that identified and recorded the date and time a tagged fish passed by. The resulting data are an irregularly spaced time series of a fish's (nominal) pattern of upstream or downstream movement. I want to test the independence of a sequence of a fish's movements, e.g., is a fish's downstream movement more or less likely to be followed by a subsequent downstream movement? Each fish data series is not very long (<20 data points) I've studied categorical time series but cannot find a way to handle irregularly spaced nominal observations. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I want to know if a fish's sequence of up-/downstream movements exhibits autocorrelation. Is a fish's movement direction correlated with the previous movement direction, accounting for the elapsed time between movements (if elapsed time is long I would downweight any autocorrelation). There are methodologies for irregular spaced scalar-valued time series, but my time series is categorical. I wish do this to support analysis of environmental influences such as day-night cycle on the direction of movement analyzed using circular statistics, which requires independence of observations.
